# Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.WebJarAssets

Tags: java, sbt, playframework-2.4, webjars

I have a simple play framework application. I added webjars dependency to handle some bootstrap libraries I added. I keep getting the following error when I try to access one of my resource form screens.

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.WebJarAssets. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at controllers.WebJarAssets.class(WebJarAssets.scala:18)
  while locating controllers.WebJarAssets
    for parameter 4 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:40)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router

1 error]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:165) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
```

Here's my sbt file.

```
name := """PlankTeamAwards"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += evolutions

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.2"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Here's my routes file

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /hello                      controllers.Application.hello(name:String)

# Employees 
GET     /employees/                 controllers.Employees.list()
GET     /employees/new              controllers.Employees.showBlank()
GET     /employees/:employeeId      controllers.Employees.show(employeeId: Long)
POST    /employees/                 controllers.Employees.save()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
GET     /webjars/*file                  controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

And here is my main.scala.html file where I am referencing the boostrap css files.

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("css/bootstrap.min.css"))'>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest `webjars-play`:

```
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-2"
```

Comment: That did not help. I must be missing something.

Comment: I removed my .ivy2 folder and re-ran the application and it worked. I think the upgrade to latest webjars-play also helped.

Comment: A restart of the app / build should have been sufficient.  But glad it eventually worked.

Comment: For some reason that did not work. It could be something to do with my local setup. This could be an option of last resort.